# Opensea seaport protocol works with Eip712 offline signatures only through permit method of tokens?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, opensea, eip712, seaport

I try understand how offline signatures work with seaport protocol for example.
Seaport use offline sign to make operations in token contract behalf signer of offline signature (eip712). But token contracts have only permit method where can be used offline signatures. Does it mean what offline signatures only works with that tokens that have permit method and doesn't work with another token contracts?